# How to send a group message to multiple receivers using GSM900 and Arduino Mega2560?

Tags: programming, arduino-mega, gsm, coding-standards

I'm working on a project and it can send to one receiver only. What I need is to send a message to multiple receivers. I need a code sample that would satisfy my needs. Please help! I need to finish this ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the number in the AT command and send the message again.